# simple bitwise operation for three state variable

Tags: c#-4.0, logic

I have an object that can has 3 different state variables that are Boolean.
The rule is that only one of the 3 can be true at any one time.  All others must be false.

I'm writing server-side validation and need to confirm this rule.
Is there a simple operation that I can use that will test for only one state being true?

I prefer to avoid the triple If logic for this.

UPDATE: This is not in ASP.NET.  The record being passed is 3 booleans.  The object is passed via json serialization.  So I'm working with what is given me.

Comment: (a & !b & !c) | (!a & b & !c) | (!a & !b & c)

Comment: @AkramBerkawy: and now the same with 10 `bools` ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: the question was :simple bitwise operation for three state variable.:D i'm who voted on your answer ;)

Comment: @AkramBerkawy: I also specified I wanted to avoid the triple if logic.  Specifically for what Tim stated: what if they add 3 more questions or states?

Comment: @SASS_Shooter "simple bitwise operation for three state variable"...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object has three `bool` properties and only one should be `true`,  I like this approach:

```
public static int TrueCount(params bool[] booleans)
{
    return booleans.Count(b => b);
}
```

Then it's simple:

```
bool onlyOneTrue = TrueCount(obj.Pprop1, obj.Prop2, obj.Prop3) == 1;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/bvXvmX)

<sup>Note that [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) needs `using System.Linq;`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not using the right type - you should probably be using an enumeration with three values.

```
public enum ThreeThings
{
  state1,
  state2,
  state3
}
```

With an enumeration, given a valid enumeration value, it can only be one of the three.